# How to take user input as tuple and then printing said tuple

Tags: python, tuples, user-input

Very new at python and im trying to figure out how to write a program to ask the users to input the courses and teachers into a tuple and then have users input "done" as an end. To finish it off i need to print the tuple. Any tips?

such as:

"Please enter your courses:" math

"Please enter your teacher:" John

"Please enter your courses:" done

('math', 'john', etc...)

Comment: i was using a while loop to handle input and ending by "done", i could do this with a list but i have trouble understanding how these tuples work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to add values iteratively, tuples will not be the best choice for this since they are immutable, You can use either dictionary or lists.

Using Lists:

```
arr = []
while True:
    course = input("Please enter your courses: ")
    teacher = input("Please enter your teacher: ")
    if course=='done' or techer=='done':
        break
    arr.append((course,teacher))
```

Using Dicts

```
d = {}
while True:
    course = input("Please enter your courses: ")
    teacher = input("Please enter your teacher: ")
    if course=='done' or techer=='done':
        break
    d[course]=teacher
```

Comment: It would be a nicer UX if you checked `course=='done'` before asking for teacher.

Answer (score 0):

The user can't input a tuple directly; you'll have to accept each input separately and assemble them into a tuple yourself:

```
course = input('enter course: ')
teacher = input('enter teacher:' )
mytuple = course, teacher
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = []
while True:
    course = input("Please enter the courses you are taking this semester: ")
    if course == 'done':
        break
    professor = input("Please enter the professor's name for the course: ")
    if professor == 'done':
        break
    lst.append((course, professor))

def convert(lst):
    return tuple(lst)

print(convert(lst))
```

this is what i came up with, thank you